# Get details of flagged questions

Tags: discussion, flags, down-votes

Can anyone tell me how long it will take a moderator to give details about a flag? Can a moderator roll back my reputation, if I am downvoted by mistake?

Comment: It's unlikely you were downvoted by mistake...

Comment: But what about fraudulent voting

Comment: What do you mean by "giving details about flag"? What specific flag are you talking about, and what do you expect?

Comment: @RaviBagul Serial downvoting is reversed automatically. Any other kind of downvoting is unlikely to be fraudulent.

Comment: I solved one problem and posted an answer,but some one down vote me. why?

Comment: @RaviBagul The tooltip on the downvote button reads "This answer is not useful". Apparently someone thought so.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Then how are you sure it was serial voting? If you suspect it was, you have the option of flagging any of those posts and requesting an investigation.

Comment: If you meant [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20834548/2389310) then I can't blame downvoter. A block of code with no explanation at all is not particularly useful.

Comment: Sorry Friends. I think my answer really was not so helpful.Thank you again.

Comment: @RaviBagul: you can still improve it if you have the skills and then it will be upvoted by the users, I believe.

Comment: Ravi, you posted two Answers to the same Question; normally, that's not necessary. Maybe they can be merged into one, and more complete, single Answer. The guide [answer] can help you.

Comment: @LaszloPapp - For the record, the only string of 7+ targeted votes against your account was indeed reversed by the system on Sept. 10: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2682142/laszlo-papp?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=3 . If there is another such grouping of votes that we're missing (unlikely, given the tools we have at our disposal), flag and we'll take a look at it.

Comment: @Brad: it was not just about me, but the script did not catch one instance out there that I am aware of. Feel free to contact me in private. I do not feel comfortable about talking it in public anymore, at least as of now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moderators, in general, do not interfere with voting and only have  very limited access to information about votes. Specifically we do not have a way to tell if a vote is "by mistake" only the user who cast the vote can tell that. Please don't flag for moderator attention for general voting.

(The one exception is fraudulent voting where we can and do intervene if it is seen - please do flag if you see evidence of that).

In terms of the time taken to investigate a flag it totally depends on what the flag says and what we see when we start looking. Some flags are trivial to judge and act upon, some require more detailed investigation. If a flag is clearly explained and has merit then someone will take the necessary time to look over it and act appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Moderators will not spend time for the information of who has down-voted you. Nobody must give information about that since it is private.

Normally, system warns the down-voter to write the reason of the down-vote, so owner of the question/answer can fix his mistake. But there is no rule that a down-voter **must** explain his reason. If you receive a down-vote, then you can ask for the reason of it.

If your question/answer is poor (poor covers many things in here please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section) then you may get a downvote without any explanation since users expects you to read that section before you ask/answer.

There is a protection system that track the down-votes, so it is hard to do a *serial down-vote*, But if you have suspects on that, then you can ask help from a mod. But for that suspect, you must receive many down-votes in a short time where there is no reason for a down-vote according to faq.